# How to add image to emulator's gallery in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am testing a HarmonyOS application and want to add an image to the emulator's gallery.

In Android Studio, we can send any file into the android emulator via drag-n-drop action,
but drag-n-drop isn't working here.

What is the alternative for this in HarmonyOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

You can transfer files in HarmonyOS Simulators from your computer via the following command, images will appear in Gallery once pushed -

**Steps:**

1. Make sure the device (Simulator / Phone) is running.
2. Run DevEcoStudio -> Open Terminal.
3. Make sure the Device is connected to DevEcoStudio.
4. Make sure you have HMOS_Home set in environment variables in your computer.
5. Run `hdc file send` command with arguments. The terminal will show messages with success or failure after execution.

   **`hdc file send [LOCAL file path of computer] [REMOTE location in device]`**

Example - [image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, drag-and-drop is not supported. You can run the following HDC command to transfer files:

`hdc file send D:/a.jpg /sdcard`